# Xcode 15, C++ compilation error. I recently updated to xcode15 and Sonoma as well. Now when I run C++ files I am getting compilation error

Tags: xcode, gcc, compiler-errors, xcode-command-line-tools

I recently updated to xcode15 and Sonoma as well. Now when I run C++ files I am getting compilation error.

```
-macosx_version_min has been renamed to -macos_version_min
ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lgcc'
0  0x1003ef648  __assert_rtn + 72
1  0x100323fac  ld::AtomPlacement::findAtom(unsigned char, unsigned long long, ld::AtomPlacement::AtomLoc const*&, long long&) const + 1204
2  0x100339924  ld::InputFiles::SliceParser::parseObjectFile(mach_o::Header const*) const + 15164
3  0x100346e30  ld::InputFiles::parseAllFiles(void (ld::AtomFile const*) block_pointer)::$_7::operator()(unsigned long, ld::FileInfo const&) const + 420
4  0x187c4d950  _dispatch_client_callout2 + 20
5  0x187c60ba0  _dispatch_apply_invoke + 176
6  0x187c4d910  _dispatch_client_callout + 20
7  0x187c5f3cc  _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 864
8  0x187c5fa04  _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 156
9  0x187df70d8  _pthread_wqthread + 228
ld: Assertion failed: (resultIndex < sectData.atoms.size()), function findAtom, file Relocations.cpp, line 1336.
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Now since I have updated my OS as well I am not able to downgrade Xcode.

So do any of u know what I can do to fix this issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.